# Help with a AppEngine Handler Regex?

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

I've been trying to design a Google AppEngine Python handler regex and haven't been too successful in getting it to work.

I'm trying to handle API calls similar to [OpenStreetMap's](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6).

My current regex looks like this:

```
/api/0.6/(.*?)/(.*?)\/?(.*?)
```

But when this comes in:

```
/api/0.6/changeset/723/close
```

It incorrectly groups `723/close` and `changeset`, when I wanted it to group it into three things: `changeset`, `723`, and `close`.

The last slash and group is optional, thus the `/?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/api/0.6/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)$
```

My Python tests:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"^/api/0.6/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)$")
>>> regex.match("/api/0.6/changeset") is None
True
>>> regex.match("/api/0.6/changeset/723").groups()
('changeset', '723', '')
>>> regex.match("/api/0.6/changeset/723/close").groups()
('changeset', '723', 'close')
>>> regex.match("/api/0.6/changeset/723/close/extragroup") is None
True
```